# I'm not getting the expected result from ADF Filter Transformation

Tags: azure-data-factory

In ADF data mapping, I have the column SensitiveRecord with the possibilities (Yes - No - Allow - Null).

I want to filter out the "Yes".

*I'm using the expression SensitiveRecord != "Yes".*

**The Problem: It only retrieved the "No" rows, while i was expecting "No", "Allow" and N**ull!

Could you please help where I went wrong! Thanks

Comment: How many rows are in your dataset? The data preview feature in ADF defaults to 1000 rows. Is it possible that the other values are not present in those 1000 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick repro (considering column `SensitiveRecord` is of `String` DataType) as below and seems the scenario might be as Mark mentioned with respect to the dataset or user configuration such as `Sampling` or `Batching` or `partitioning` at the source dataset.

Make sure records with all possible values for the column `SensitiveRecord` occur atleast once in the source dataset to have best results.

**Example:**

**Source:**
[image]

**Filter:**
[image]

**Result:**
[image]

Refer: [Sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source#:%7E:text=of%20the%20dataset.-,Sampling,-%3A%20Enable%20Sampling%20to) , [Data preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-debug-mode?tabs=data-factory#data-preview) and [partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source#optimize-the-source-transformation)  for more details from official MS docs.

Comment: Thank you so much @karthikBhyresh  for taking the time to look at this issue. Im still not quite sure how it worked for you! I went with this (isNull(SensitiveRecord) || SensitiveRecord != 'Yes') and it worked for now. My dataset is about 1.4 million record. Thanks again